# IndexError: index 748 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 (when i train my CNN)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I wrote the following code:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

# Create a dataset subclass
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
  # constructor for input data
  def __init__(self, data, labels):
    super().__init__()
    self.data = data
    self.labels = labels

  def __len__(self):
    return self.data.shape[0] # return of the number of images

  def __getitem__(self, index): # function that returns the image and its label
    data =  torch.from_numpy(self.data[index]).type(torch.float32)
    labels = torch.tensor([self.labels[index]]).type(torch.int64)
    return data, labels
  
trainset = CustomDataset(train_set_tr, labels_ch)

trainloader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)




# create a CNN

from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torchsummary import summary

class CNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self): # function that defines the architecture of CNN
    super().__init__()
    # convolutional features
    self.conv_features = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=24, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
        )

    
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(24*3*3,256)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256,10)

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv_features(x)
    x = x.view(x.size()[0], -1) # flattening
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    return self.fc2(x)

model = CNN().to('cuda')
summary(model, (3,28,28), device='cuda')




#train CNN
from torch.optim import SGD

num_epochs = 5

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum = 0.9)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  total_loss = 0
  for images, labels in trainloader:
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Make the prediction
    logits = model(images.to('cuda'))

    # Calculate train loss
    loss = criterion(logits, labels.to('cuda'))
    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()
    total_loss += float(loss.cpu().detach())

print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}: total_mean_loss: {total_loss/len(train_set)}')
```

in order to train my CNN. My `trainset` consists of the `train_set_tr` that has 18900 RGB images with dimensions (18900, 3, 64, 64) and the `labels_ch` that has the labels of each image with dimensions (1, 18900).
When i run my code i get the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-30a75dc4fdc6> in <module>()
      9 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
     10   total_loss = 0
---> 11   for images, labels in trainloader:
     12     optimizer.zero_grad()
     13 

4 frames
<ipython-input-73-d3f7c554eaa2> in __getitem__(self, index)
     14   def __getitem__(self, index): # function that returns the image and its label
     15     data =  torch.from_numpy(self.data[index]).type(torch.float32)
---> 16     labels = torch.tensor([self.labels[index]]).type(torch.int64)
     17     return data, labels
     18 

IndexError: index 748 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I searched for a solution here but i can not find an answer. What is causing this error?

Comment: Im pretty sure you need to get your ```labels``` list to the shape of (18900, 1)

Comment: You are right. This is the solution.